# How to halt a database registration until a validation code is accepted through emails in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I am trying to create a WinForms program in c# that emails a user a random validation code, and if they accept, then they can log into their account.

Otherwise, access is denied. How would I go about doing this?

I have a site that can email others, but is there anyway in linking my code with the site so the site sends them the email and then sees if they accepted then tells my application they accepted?

1. They register.
2. Email is sent to them with randomly generated validation.
3. They click on the validation code.
4. They can now login into the C# WinForms application.

Comment: If you send a code, would it not be simpler to ask the user to enter the code back in the WinForm dialog instead of clicking on a link in the email?

Comment: @Luc Morin I think I will do that! Wow! That saved a me a lot of coding! Thanks Luc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite possible. You need to notify your application when your server receive acceptance from user.

This can be achieved by setting up a channel between your server code and application using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) OR [Socket.io](http://Socket.io). You can do this with [long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/) with server by your application to check whether user has accepted or not.

Comment: I will look into that! Thanks!